# Importing large IDL files into Python with SciPy

Tags: python, out-of-memory

I currently use scipy.io.readsav() to import IDL .sav files to Python, which is working well, eg:

```
data = scipy.io.readsav('data.sav', python_dict=True, verbose=True)
```

However, if the .sav file is large (say > 1 GB), I get a MemoryError when trying to import into Python.

Usually, iterating through the data would of course solve this (if it were a .txt or .csv file) rather than loading it in all in at once, but I don't see how I can do this when using .sav files, considering the only method I know of to import it is using readsav.

Any ideas how I can avoid this memory error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You expressed interest in iterating over a .sav file. One (not too onerous) way to do this would be to write a lightweight wrapper class or function to use instead of SciPy's `readsav()`, using the slightly lower-level functions in the `scipy.io.idl` module, such as [`_read_record()`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.12.0/scipy/io/_idl.py#L316-L421).

Using that function, one could do something like the following:

```py
from scipy.io import idl

def sav_iterator(file_path):
    fp = open(file_path, "rb") # open file for reading in raw bytes mode
    signature = fp.read(2) # should be b'SR'
    recfmt = fp.read(2) # should be b'\x00\x04' for uncompressed
    while True:
        record_dict = idl._read_record(fp) # parses dict and advances file pointer accordingly
        yield record_dict
        if record_dict["rectype"] == "END_MARKER":
            break # stop iteration
    fp.close() # close the file object once we're done with it
    return

for record in sav_iterator("my_data.sav"):
    do_something_with(record) # placeholder
```

With this method, only one record's worth of data ever needs to be held in memory at a time.

Answer (score 0):

This was resolved by using 64 bit python.